# What will happen if the panelist in my thesis defense does not like my thesis in College level? Will I fail?

Tags: thesis, thesis-committee, defense

I am currently graduating student and having a thesis project to pass the course and requirement for graduation. Is it possible to fail the my program if the panelist in my defense does not like my thesis? Does it affect my possibility to pass the course and graduate?

Comment: Say something about numbers. Are there several "panelists"? Are you asking about the opinion of one of many or something else? Is your thesis advisor a member in any sense?

Comment: Panelists don't fail students and prevent them from graduating on a whim. What does your thesis project advisor say about your work?

Answer (score 4):

It wouldn't be an exam if there were no possibility of failure. So the answer is "yes, it is possible to fail". The consequences of failing would depend on your program. If passing the thesis project is a requirement for graduation, then odds are you will not be able to graduate, but you'll get another chance to pass the thesis project next semester / next year.

Comment: Put is a thesis defense always an exam? (Or is it a ritual?)

Answer (score 2):

As @allure already says, it wouldn't be an exam if there wasn't the possibility for failure. But it's worth remembering that (i) it isn't about "liking a thesis", but assessing *whether a candidate has the qualifications required to pass a certain level, and (ii) the people on your panel are professionals with many years of experience in evaluating theses. As a consequence, panelists will be able to make a difference between "I don't like this" and "I don't think this candidate is qualified". Of course, in the latter case the candidate should not pass, but it isn't because the panelist doesn't like you or your thesis.